# Playing audio files from a password protected Http directory

Tags: c#, xamarin, media-player, http-authentication

I'm working on a little mobile application in Xamarin, i'm using XamarinMediaManager to play audio files from a URL using CrossMediaManager.Current.Play() which takes a string as URL. If i set up a name and a password on the directory that includes the MP3 is there a way for me to include the credentials and play it?

I could successfully access the password protected directory if i use an HttpWebResponse and set the credentials but i can't seem to find a way to pass that on to the CrossMediaManager

Thank you for the help in advance

Comment: Did you try to add a method that check firstly the password and then run your audio file?

Comment: How are you password protecting it?

Comment: @taktak What do you mean by check the password first?

Comment: @Cheesebaron I'm using Hostinger to host my site and there's an option in the cpanel to protect certain directories, when accessing it from a browser a prompt pops up(generated by the browser) asking for a username and password

Comment: can you try adding: `username:password@` infront of the URL like: `https://username:password@myhost.com/folder/song.mp3`? Alternatively you need to set the `Authorization` header to `Authorization: Basic <base64>` where `<base64>` is `username:password` encoded in base 64

Comment: @Cheesebaron Unfortunately the first approach doesn't seem to work even when trying to access it that way through the browser (Chrome, Edge), still prompts me for the username and password and the files won't play on xamarin. Could you elaborate on the second solution? i'm not sure where that header could be set from since the mediaplayer doesn't give me access to any http related properties. Additionally, i noticed that the password protection is created using .htaccess and .htpasswd on the directory

Comment: You can set RequestHeaders for the CrossMediaManager.

Comment: Thanks it worked!

Comment: string svcCredentials = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username" + ":" + "password"));
            CrossMediaManager.Current.RequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + svcCredentials);

Comment: ^ These are the exact lines i used

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem i followed the recommendation that @Cheesebaron gave me and set an Authorization header to RequestHeaders on CrossMediaManager. Here's the exact lines i used

```
string svcCredentials = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username" + ":" + "password")); 
CrossMediaManager.Current.RequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + svcCredentials);
```